# Why does Ubuntu takes so long to reconnect to the Wifi after Suspend mode

Tags: wireless, suspend, 17.04, xps

I am using Ubuntu on an XPS 15 9550. On Windows, when I suspend my computer by closing the lid and then wake up my laptop the WiFi connects immediately. However, with Ubuntu it takes approximately 10 seconds in order to do so. Why is that? Is there any way to reduce this lag?